# Challenge-response login without storing a password equivalent

Tags: passwords, authentication, hash

A problem with many challenge-response login systems is that the server has to store a password equivalent. For example, if the server stores SHA1(salt + password), and an attacker captures that hash, then they would be able to directly use the hash to login, without having to crack the password.

I believe there are some variations of challenge-response login that avoid this weakness. In particular, I have heard that newer versions of MySQL have fixed it. I do not have any references or further information on this, but I would like to know how this can be done. I can imagine some approaches myself, but I would prefer to use a standard, peer-reviewed protocol.

I am aware that SRP solves this problem. However, SRP is more a public key protocol rather than challenge-response. I am particularly interested in protocols that only use symmetric ciphers, hashes, and maybe some XORing, etc.

Comment: How do they directly use the hash to login?  If they provide the hash, the server will try salting and hashing the hash, get a different value than what it has stored and fail the authentication.

Comment: @AJHenderson - this specifically about challenge-response logins. A typical setup is that the server stores hash(salt+password) and to login a user must send hash(challenge+hash(salt+password)). In that case, if an attacker already knows hash(salt+password) they can complete the login process and impersonate the user.

Comment: why does the server bother storing a hash rather than the actual secret then?  The hash serves no purpose other than to increase the time it takes to authenticate.  A challenge response should be hash(challenge + secret + salt).  I guess that your question is if there is a way to do it without having to store the secret on the server though right? (since the normal algorithm still requires storing the secret used by the user.)

Comment: @AJHenderson - fair question, but somewhat moot as the link from timoh has a better solution.

Comment: yeah, I was just trying to understand the question because the use of a hash to generate the secret from the password serves no purpose.  It doesn't answer your question (which is why I commented), it was just something that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @AJHenderson - yes, that's exactly what I'm asking. And although the setup I explain might seem silly, it is extremely widely used, being the basis of NTLM, MySQL auth, APOP, and I expect much more.

Comment: ah, yeah, looks like unix style systems tend to do it just because people may have a tendency to use the same password in multiple places and because the user-login locally still requires the real password.  So they are trying to avoid allowing local login even if the network authentication itself would be fubar.  Still a weak case in my opinion, but at least I understand the reasoning now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the algorithms described here suits your description (doesn't require to store plaintext-equivalents on the server, achieves stretching and are simpler than public-key setups): http://openwall.info/wiki/people/solar/algorithms/challenge-response-authentication